# How to validate data that was altered in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several validations that validate a `Quote` object. Upon validation, I have a `before_save` callback that calls an API and grabs more data, makes a few math computations and then saves the newly computed data in the database.

I don't want to trust the API response entirely so I need to validate the data I compute.

Please note that the API call in the `before_save` callback is dependent on the prior validations.

For example:

```
validates :subtotal, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
before_save :call_api_and_compute_tax
before_save :compute_grand_total
#I want to validate the tax and grand total numbers here to make sure something strange wasn't returned from the API.
```

I need to be able to throw a validation error if possible with something like:

```
errors.add :base, "Tax didn't calculate correctly."
```

How can I validate values that were computed in my `before_save` callbacks?

Comment: Personal opinion: AR callbacks are bad, and network activity in an AR callback is really bad. I'd reorganize to avoid the callback, using [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or "service object".

Comment: @JaredBeck I did a bit of reading after seeing your comment and I am now of the same opinion. Thanks for your insight, I learned a lot researching this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `after_validation`

```
after_validation :call_api_and_compute_tax, :compute_grand_total

def call_api_and_compute_tax
  return false if self.errors.any?

  if ... # not true
    errors.add :base, "Tax didn't calculate correctly."
  end
end

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding custom validation methods before save? I think this is a good approach to verify validation errors before calling save method

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :api_and_compute_tax

  private

  def api_and_compute_tax
    # ...API call and result parse
    if api_with_wrong_response?
      errors.add :base, "Tax didn't calculate correctly."
    end
  end
end
```

Then you should call it like

```
quote.save if quote.valid? # this will execute your custom validation
```

Comment: Yes I have. My only issue is that some of the `before_save` callbacks that need to run prior to the tax api call and validation don't really have any data to validate but they don't need to run if there are validation issues which leaves me with validate callbacks that aren't really validations. It just seems weird but it may be my only option.

Comment: But there is no such thing as 'validate callbacks'. Callbacks is just some code to run around the model's actions, the validations is part of the beginning, so i think you have a misconception about callbacks and validations.